# Does AWS VPC endpoint has limit of connections to the target AWS resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint, aws-private-link

Does AWS VPC interface endpoint (PrivateLink) has a limit of ongoing or new connections to the target AWS resource?

For example if I have a AWS service (Lambda) connecting to SQS through VPC interface endpoint.

No information about limits on the following docs:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/what-is-privatelink.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-limits-endpoints.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A VPC Endpoint is a **logical construct for defining networking connections**. It is not a physical device.

A VPC Endpoint does not limit the number of connections, but the **destination resource** might limit the number of *incoming* connections, or might have a limit on the available incoming bandwidth.

Comment: Is this true? VPC Endpoints retain an static eni? They also hold vpc flow logs